# Bad : modifier in $ ($)

Tags: linux, csh

I have written small script and getting bad mofied error. not able to figure out what i am missing here. the cth_pythonpath variable exist into environment and able to print variable

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set script_rootdir = `dirname $0`

set script_abs_rootdir = `realpath $script_rootdir`

setenv PYTHONPATH $CTH_PYTHONPATH:$PYTHONPATH
```

Error:

```
Bad : modifier in $ ($).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csh allows variable modifiers in the form of `$varname:x`, where `x` is a letter. Some examples are `:e` to get the extension, `:q` to quote the string, and a whole bunch more. For example:

```
> set path = 'file.txt'
> echo $path:e
txt
```

The problem you're running in to is that this:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH $CTH_PYTHONPATH:$PYTHONPATH
```

That the same syntax: `$CTH_PYTHONPATH` ends with a `:`, so it tries to apply the `$` modifier, but this modifier doesn't exist so you get the error:

```
Bad : modifier in $ ($).
```

The solution is to use `${varname}` to explicitly tell csh when the variable name ends or using quotes:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH ${CTH_PYTHONPATH}:${PYTHONPATH}
setenv PYTHONPATH "$CTH_PYTHONPATH":"$PYTHONPATH"
```

I recommend quoting variables by the way; it will prevent problems with spaces and the like; I'd probably write this as:

```
setenv PYTHONPATH "${CTH_PYTHONPATH}:${PYTHONPATH}"
```

---

Note that I don't recommend using csh if you can help it by the way; it's an old shell with a lot of problems, including strange errors in all sorts of cases. Note how the error you have doesn't print the line number or is really very helpful.